# How to use code that relies on ThreadLocal with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Some JVM frameworks use `ThreadLocal` to store the call context of a application, like the [SLF4j MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html), transaction managers, security managers, and others.

However, Kotlin coroutines are dispatched on different threads, so how it can be made to work?

(The question is inspired by [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/119))

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Coroutine's analog to `ThreadLocal` is [`CoroutineContext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/).

To interoperate with `ThreadLocal`-using libraries you need to implement a custom [`ContinuationInterceptor`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-continuation-interceptor/index.html) that supports framework-specific thread-locals.

Here is an example. Let us assume that we use some framework that relies on a specific `ThreadLocal` to store some application-specific data (`MyData` in this example):

```
val myThreadLocal = ThreadLocal<MyData>()
```

To use it with coroutines, you'll need to implement a context that keeps the current value of `MyData` and puts it into the corresponding `ThreadLocal` every time the coroutine is resumed on a thread. The code should look like this:

```
class MyContext(
    private var myData: MyData,
    private val dispatcher: ContinuationInterceptor
) : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(ContinuationInterceptor), ContinuationInterceptor {
    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> =
        dispatcher.interceptContinuation(Wrapper(continuation))

    inner class Wrapper<T>(private val continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> {
        private inline fun wrap(block: () -> Unit) {
            try {
                myThreadLocal.set(myData)
                block()
            } finally {
                myData = myThreadLocal.get()
            }
        }

        override val context: CoroutineContext get() = continuation.context
        override fun resume(value: T) = wrap { continuation.resume(value) }
        override fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable) = wrap { continuation.resumeWithException(exception) }
    }
}
```

To use it in your coroutines, you wrap the dispatcher that you want to use with `MyContext` and give it the initial value of your data. This value will be put into the thread-local on the thread where the coroutine is resumed.

```
launch(MyContext(MyData(), CommonPool)) {
    // do something...
}
```

The implementation above would also track any changes to the thread-local that was done and store it in this context, so this way multiple invocation can share "thread-local" data via context.

**UPDATE**: Starting with `kotlinx.corutines` version `0.25.0` there is direct support for representing Java `ThreadLocal` instances as coroutine context elements. See [this documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#thread-local-data) for details. There is also out-of-the-box support for SLF4J MDC via `kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j` integration module.

Comment: Does Kotlin Coroutine or Spring have any build-in supports for the bridge between Kotlin Coroutine and Spring transaction?

Comment: No, but it takes just a few lines to write those. We hope that Spring will provide the corresponding support in the future

Comment: I believe the APIs have changed a bit since this was written. Still helpful though!

Answer (score 4):

Though this question is quite an old one, but I would want to add to Roman's answer another possible approach with `CopyableThreadContextElement`. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody else.

```
// Snippet from the source code's comment
class TraceContextElement(private val traceData: TraceData?) : CopyableThreadContextElement<TraceData?> {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<TraceContextElement>

    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<TraceContextElement> = Key

    override fun updateThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext): TraceData? {
        val oldState = traceThreadLocal.get()
        traceThreadLocal.set(traceData)
        return oldState
    }

    override fun restoreThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext, oldState: TraceData?) {
        traceThreadLocal.set(oldState)
    }

    override fun copyForChild(): TraceContextElement {
        // Copy from the ThreadLocal source of truth at child coroutine launch time. This makes
        // ThreadLocal writes between resumption of the parent coroutine and the launch of the
        // child coroutine visible to the child.
        return TraceContextElement(traceThreadLocal.get()?.copy())
    }

    override fun mergeForChild(overwritingElement: CoroutineContext.Element): CoroutineContext {
        // Merge operation defines how to handle situations when both
        // the parent coroutine has an element in the context and
        // an element with the same key was also
        // explicitly passed to the child coroutine.
        // If merging does not require special behavior,
        // the copy of the element can be returned.
        return TraceContextElement(traceThreadLocal.get()?.copy())
    }
}
```

Note that `copyForChild` method allows you to propagate thread local data taken from the parent coroutine's last resumption phase to the local context of the child coroutine (as `Copyable` in `CopyableThreadContextElement` implies), because method `copyForChild` will be invoked on the parent coroutine's thread associated with the corresponding resumption phase when a child coroutine was created.

Just by adding `TraceContextElement` context element to the root coroutine's context it will be propagated to all child coroutines as context element.

```
  runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO + TraceContextElement(someTraceDataInstance)){...}
```

Whereas with `ContinuationInterceptor` approach additional wrapping can be necessary for child coroutines' builders, if you redefine dispatchers for child coroutines.

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking(WrappedDispatcher(Dispatchers.IO)) {
        delay(100)
        println("It is wrapped!")
        delay(100)
        println("It is also wrapped!")
        // NOTE: we don't wrap with the WrappedDispatcher class here
        // redefinition of the dispatcher leads to replacement of our custom ContinuationInterceptor
        // with logic taken from specified dispatcher (in the case below from Dispatchers.Default)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            delay(100)
            println("It is nested coroutine, and it isn't wrapped!")
            delay(100)
            println("It is nested coroutine, and it isn't wrapped!")
        }
        delay(100)
        println("It is also wrapped!")
    }
}
```

with wrapper overriding `ContinuationInterceptor` interface

```
class WrappedDispatcher(
    private val dispatcher: ContinuationInterceptor
) : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(ContinuationInterceptor), ContinuationInterceptor {

    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> =
        dispatcher.interceptContinuation(ContinuationWrapper(continuation))

    private class ContinuationWrapper<T>(val base: Continuation<T>) : Continuation<T> by base {

        override fun resumeWith(result: Result<T>) {
            println("------WRAPPED START-----")
            base.resumeWith(result)
            println("------WRAPPED END-------")
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
------WRAPPED START-----
------WRAPPED END-------
------WRAPPED START-----
It is wrapped!
------WRAPPED END-------
------WRAPPED START-----
It is also wrapped!
------WRAPPED END-------
It is nested coroutine, and it isn't wrapped!
It is nested coroutine, and it isn't wrapped!
------WRAPPED START-----
------WRAPPED END-------
------WRAPPED START-----
It is also wrapped!
------WRAPPED END-------
```

as you can see for the child (nested) coroutine our wrapper wasn't applied, since we reassigned a `ContinuationInterceptor` supplying another dispatcher as a parameter. This can lead to a problem as you can mistakenly forget to wrap a child coroutine's dispatcher.

---

As a side note, if you decide to choose this approach with `ContinuationInterceptor`, then consider to add such extension

```
fun ContinuationInterceptor.withMyProjectWrappers() = WrappedDispatcher(this)
```

wrapping your dispatcher with all necessary wrappers you have in the project, obviously it can be easily extended taking specific beans (wrappers) from an IoC container such as Spring.

---

And also as an extra example of `CopyableThreadContextElement` where thread local changes are saved in all resumptions phases.

> `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(..).asCoroutineDispatcher()` is used to
> better illustrate that different threads can be working between
> resumptions phases.

```
val counterThreadLocal: ThreadLocal<Int> = ThreadLocal.withInitial{ 1 }

fun showCounter(){
    println("-------------------------------------------------")
    println("Thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}\n Counter value: ${counterThreadLocal.get()}")
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10).asCoroutineDispatcher() + CounterPropagator(1)) {
        showCounter()
        delay(100)
        showCounter()
        counterThreadLocal.set(2)
        delay(100)
        showCounter()
        counterThreadLocal.set(3)
        val nested = async(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10).asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
            println("-----------NESTED START---------")
            showCounter()
            delay(100)
            counterThreadLocal.set(4)
            showCounter()
            println("------------NESTED END-----------")
        }
        nested.await()
        showCounter()
        println("---------------END------------")
    }
}

class CounterPropagator(private var counterFromParenCoroutine: Int) : CopyableThreadContextElement<Int> {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<CounterPropagator>

    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<CounterPropagator> = Key

    override fun updateThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext): Int {
        // initialize thread local on the resumption
        counterThreadLocal.set(counterFromParenCoroutine)
        return 0
    }

    override fun restoreThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext, oldState: Int) {
        // propagate thread local changes between resumption phases in the same coroutine
        counterFromParenCoroutine = counterThreadLocal.get()
    }

    override fun copyForChild(): CounterPropagator {
        // propagate thread local changes to children
        return CounterPropagator(counterThreadLocal.get())
    }

    override fun mergeForChild(overwritingElement: CoroutineContext.Element): CoroutineContext {
        return CounterPropagator(counterThreadLocal.get())
    }
}
```

output:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Thread: pool-1-thread-1
 Counter value: 1
-------------------------------------------------
Thread: pool-1-thread-2
 Counter value: 1
-------------------------------------------------
Thread: pool-1-thread-3
 Counter value: 2
-----------NESTED START---------
-------------------------------------------------
Thread: pool-2-thread-1
 Counter value: 3
-------------------------------------------------
Thread: pool-2-thread-2
 Counter value: 4
------------NESTED END-----------
-------------------------------------------------
Thread: pool-1-thread-4
 Counter value: 3
---------------END------------
```

You can achieve similar behavior with `ContinuationInterceptor` (but don't forget to re-wrap dispatchers of child (nested) coroutines in the coroutine builder as was mentioned above)

```
val counterThreadLocal: ThreadLocal<Int> = ThreadLocal()

class WrappedDispatcher(
    private val dispatcher: ContinuationInterceptor,
    private var savedCounter: Int = counterThreadLocal.get() ?: 0
) : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(ContinuationInterceptor), ContinuationInterceptor {
    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> =
        dispatcher.interceptContinuation(ContinuationWrapper(continuation))

    private inner class ContinuationWrapper<T>(val base: Continuation<T>) : Continuation<T> by base {

        override fun resumeWith(result: Result<T>) {
            counterThreadLocal.set(savedCounter)
            try {
                base.resumeWith(result)
            } finally {
                savedCounter = counterThreadLocal.get()
            }
        }
    }
}
```