# Implementing SecurityService without ThreadLocal to use with Kotlin coroutine

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, micronaut, thread-local

Somewhat related to [this](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kotlin/issues/21):

We are trying to inject a SecurityService bean so that I can access the authentication object outside of a controller. Unfortunately, like the previous RequestScope implementation, the DefaultSecurityService implementation of getAuthentication relies on the ServerRequestContext.currentRequest() which is using ThreadLocal:

```java
@Override
public Optional<Authentication> getAuthentication() {
    return ServerRequestContext.currentRequest()
            .flatMap(request -> request.getUserPrincipal(Authentication.class));
}
```

And since we're also using Kotlin coroutines, we want to find a way of implementing getAuthentication without ThreadLocal. Any suggestions on how we can go about doing that?

Comment: [What about `CoroutineContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227463/10871900)?

Comment: @dan1st If I understand correctly, both [CoroutineContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227462/how-to-use-code-that-relies-on-threadlocal-with-kotlin-coroutines/46227463#46227463) and the [official support for ThreadLocal in coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#thread-local-data) requires us to specify an initial value?