# Coroutine from each request comes with a dirty ThreadLocal, Ktor 2.x.x

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, thread-local

And I haven't found a way to replicate it.

So I have a `ThreadLocal` storing a `Map<String,String>` whose initial value is an empty map.

I'm checking at the beginning of every HTTP Request, and unpredictably that `ThreadLocal` may be storing a non empty map, with values from another previous request.

I'm using the following construct:

```
withContext(threadLocal.asContextElement(someMap)){...}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227462/how-to-use-code-that-relies-on-threadlocal-with-kotlin-coroutines/46227463

Comment: If the thread was used by a previous request, then of course the `ThreadLocal` will keep whatever changes were done, using it as a context element doesn't automatically clear it when you exit `withContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent coroutine context for all requests can be configured when starting the ktor server.

When creating the embedded server multiple helper methods can be used. The most commonly used, however, passes an EmptyCoroutineContext, and so that one cannot be used.

I used

```kotlin
public fun <TEngine : ApplicationEngine, TConfiguration : ApplicationEngine.Configuration>
CoroutineScope.embeddedServer(
    factory: ApplicationEngineFactory<TEngine, TConfiguration>,
    vararg connectors: EngineConnectorConfig = arrayOf(EngineConnectorBuilder()),
    watchPaths: List<String> = listOf(WORKING_DIRECTORY_PATH),
    parentCoroutineContext: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    configure: TConfiguration.() -> Unit = {},
    module: Application.() -> Unit
): TEngine
```

insead.

Ej:

```kotlin
 GlobalScope.embeddedServer(
                Netty,
                port = config.port,
                parentCoroutineContext = myThreadLocal.asContextElement()
            ) {
                ...
            }
```